# Does it make sense to remove completely duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, clean-up, duplicate-answers

A lot of time, when I look for answers on SO I find big amount of completely duplicate answers  which do not bring any value at all, but for historical reasons they are here and some of them are even highly upvoted.

Check for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5419732/1090562). Out of 5 answers, there are only 2 different answers (actually 1). The accepted one is nicely explained with links and code, but then we have 3 same answers.

Does it make sense to somehow clean up these answers (remove them without removing points from answerers?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: the only difference is that this is not subtle different answer. It is completely the same. They do not give you any new info or additional nuances. I am speaking mostly about the anwers which just copy of another answer.

Comment: On second thought, I think I completely missed your point. You're speaking about "duplicate" answers in the same question, right? In that case, "cleaning them up" should be left to the responsibility of their respective authors IMHO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, I wrote in the title that this is duplicate answers. And we all know that their respective authors will never remove their upvoted duplicates.

Comment: Some of us do, although you're right I remember doing that only a couple of times. In this specific instance, the accepted answer is 90% copy-pasted from MSDN, so I can understand why users posting *original* one-liners with more upvotes would like to keep their answers around.

Comment: I don't see an abundance of noise on that question.  The OP checkmarked the answer that everyone needs to see anyway.

Comment: Some relevant discussion on that here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions

Comment: It looks like all the answers on that question were posted within minutes of one another so it's possible (if not very likely) that none of the answerors were aware of the other answers at the time of their submission.  From there it becomes a game of "well let the other person delete their answer because reason xyz"

Comment: related: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773) at MSE

Answer (score -6):

- Q: What is the point in asking questions?
- Q: And what happens if one answerer is unable to explain *to the asker* what the solution is?
- Q: Do you see how multiple correct answers could be helpful to the community?

People are not equal. Not in the head. Some people will understand this, and some probably will not. But somebody else could come along and explain what I've just written a different way, and you'll get it.