# What to do when there is a commonly/frequently asked question on Meta?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Today I noticed this question [Are duplicate answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable?cb=1), and I remembered that in the past I had done a similar question, and also that there are a lot of other similar questions, all with very valuable insights:

- [How to deal with duplicate answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252795/how-to-deal-with-duplicate-answers)
- [What to do with duplicated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275954/what-to-do-with-duplicated-answers)
- [Duplicate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265986/duplicate-answer)
- [Does it make sense to remove completely duplicate answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253355/does-it-make-sense-to-remove-completely-duplicate-answers)
- [Answering an old question with duplicate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289778/answering-an-old-question-with-duplicate-answer)
- [What should we do when a question is getting a lot of redundant answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284026/what-should-we-do-when-a-question-is-getting-a-lot-of-redundant-answers)
- etc.

I think this is a question that comes up a lot, but I didn't find one that you could call the "main" question/answer about the topic.

So, I was wondering, when something like this happens on Meta, what are the steps to follow? Can the information on those questions be summarized in a single post?

I wasn't sure if anything can or should be done, I appreciate your insights and guidance.

Comment: Pick the best dup target and flag / vote to close as dup.  Then we will start pointing all the dups to one place.  A lot of these questions could be marked as dups as well.

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps a FAQ could be created of this.  After all, it does seem to be asked a decent amount...

Comment: @Makoto also, I think not all the answers cover everything, I think they complement.

Comment: Let em keep coming. We need more questions here on meta, still have about 50,000 to go until quota :)

Comment: @Becuzz I noticed some of them were marked as duplicate, but sometimes the answers don't fully overlap. I agree that several of them can be marked as duplicate though.

Comment: If you are really interesting in compiling a (mostly) comprehensive faq, look at the [faq-proposed tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info).  It's a decent amount of work, but if it gets traction the community will help you out.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - I would be willing to do something like that if the consensus is that it is the most appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @Dzyann well I personally also started a faq-proposed question.  It got modest attention at first, but it died out after few days.  But it is still helpful as a better duplicate target for very similar questions.  If you are willing to write the post, then community votes/comments/alternate answers will be all the feedback/validation you need for what the "appropriate" action is.  The challenge lies (IMO) mainly in actually writing a good question, one that is "faq-worthy"

Comment: @Dzyann [a similar situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287995/comments-timestamps-can-give-away-a-review-audit/287996#comment165239_287996)

Comment: @ryanyuyu - What is the post faq-proposed question you posted?

Comment: @Dzyann http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I do not think anything is required. Most of your links are referencing posts which are related to specific answers and not necessarily the overall pattern.

While they do touch on what to do with duplicate answers, they are all centered around a specific example. As a result, closing them as duplicates of each other wouldn't be ideal because they ask different questions, even if the answer is similar in each case.

Meta here on SO used to have about 70,000 questions, and at the moment we sit at 11,000 and it took a year to get that many. My point is that I do not think that we should be worrying about an abundance of questions quite yet; so at present just keep answering these new questions even if they are of an observed frequently asked type.

In general these types of observed patterns are eligible for canonical posts. However, it is also very hard to properly create a canonical post and unless you are very familiar with not only the topic here but the depth of the discussion covered also at Meta Stack Exchange I would leave it alone.

Comment: Why do we need a moderator to do this for us?  It may take some dedication from the community, but I feel like we could handle it without their intervention.

Comment: @Makoto - You know, you are probably correct with that assertion. I removed it from my answer.

Comment: I wasn't aiming towards closing all the questions, or marking them as duplicates. I just felt that valuable information was scattered and I was wondering if we have a way to handle something like that. Also, I don't think that having less questions is really bad, if they are quality question, opposed to having a lot of duplicate ones. Although, as you say, many of the questions I liked mention specific cases, I think they are mostly illustrative rather than just referring to a particular situation. Matter of fact, I didn't link some questions that were clearly about a specific case.

Comment: @Dzyann - There is a tag for this, you could always look at improving the tag wiki. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/duplicate-answers/info

Comment: I haven't thought of that, when you search the tag text doesn't come up, it is not as handy, but I feel you are right. It is probably a good place to put the general information about duplicate-questions.