# Why so many up votes on this question and its answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality, duplicate-answers, hot-questions

I just happened to stumble across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30316505/1467396) question. At first I didn't see anything unusual, but then I noticed that there were an awful lot of duplicate answers.  Not just "similar" answers, but they mean exactly the same thing and even use many of the same words:

> "since user is a reserved word in sql you need to escape it by putting
> it in square brackets"
>
> "User is a reserved keyword, so should escape it with []"
>
> "I'm assuming you're using SQL Server (or similar) in which case USER is a reserved word. Try surrounding it with square brackets"
>
> "In sql server there are multiple reserved keywords USER is one of them... use [] for USER keyword"
>
> "You can't use the word "USER" in normal way. Because USER is a reserved word in sql. Still if you want to use it, you can use it like,
> `insert into [USER]...`"

OK, whatever.  I know there have [already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253355/1467396) [been](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252795/1467396) [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271158/1467396) [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/295148) on duplicate answers.  However, it caught my attention and made me look at it still closer.  I noticed next that the vote count seems unusually high given that the answers are all the same.  Normally, I would expect the first and/or accepted answer(s) to get almost all of the votes and the rest to be more or less ignored.  Here, the accepted one did get the lion's share, but the others were not ignored--there are a total of 72 up votes.  Does that not seem high to you?

Next, I noticed that the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25589031/1467396) [itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26197390/1467396) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495629/1467396) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30436361/1467396) [zillion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30425227/1467396) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6082412/1467396).  Again, OK, whatever... but why did this question get 17 up votes?  The [next closest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6082412/1467396) duplicate that I saw only had 9 and it's not only much older but it's also the one that a few of the other dups point to.

Finally, I noticed that for every single person involved (the OP and all answerers) this is their highest scoring post on SO by a significant margin (which would again point to this being an unusual case).

Does this look a bit fishy to anyone else?

I realize this could all be perfectly legitimate--all but one of the answers came within a few minutes of each other.  Maybe all of the players were good sports and up-voted each other.  Maybe a school is doing a project and has the students using a database with one of the tables named "user" and everyone in that class came to this question.  ...but it still looks odd to me.  You?

EDIT:
To address the [possible duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287163/1467396) that @gnat posted--I agree that this is a similar question and that the answer is probably the same. In essence, that question is "why do dumb questions do so well sometimes" while my post is "this question has been asked many times before and has never done this well--why now?"  I think it's different, but I could be persuaded otherwise.

Comment: Do you think it they may be sock puppets?  If so http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288071/how-can-i-ask-a-moderator-to-investigate-a-potential-puppet-account

Comment: Looks like easy FGITW fodder, which due to the ensuing feeding frenzy reached "Hot Network Post" status, and thus even more notoriety and votes. Shame on those who answered instead of voting to close as duplicate. No guarantee my guess is accurate.

Comment: What makes many upvotes? *) popular tags *) easy and fast to answer *) easy to judge as correct. Quality and difficulty don't really matter.

Comment: I agree with you 101%. That thread looks very fishy. The stuff there is too dumb for it to make sense. Legitimate, maybe, but still unreasonable.

Comment: Mechanics is basically the same as in linked question. Easy question, people enjoy easy answering - instead of investing _effort_ into looking for duplicates - it gets many answers fast. The only thing missing to get to hot list is now score: at SO, it has to be 5-6, at smaller sites just positive - if the question doesn't completely suck, answerers vote it up as needed, so it gets to the list... the rest is simple snowball effect. People vote up what they see without much thinking. When there are >= 5 answers, hotness formula makes process pretty much self sustaining...

Comment: ...for first 7 hours, until so called aging factor kicks in

Comment: It's deleted now...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One thing that I have learned in Question and Answer sites is that other people votes have a huge effect on other votes. 
For example if you see a question with 10 up votes, there is a big chance that you up vote it too and possibly no chance that you down vote it! 
So It's all about getting the first few up votes, the rest just comes...

Comment: Agreed with this one. Its like a project manager that negatively influences the team by stating such nonsense as "I don't know about you guys, but I think this can be built in 20 hours". And then nobody will even dare to say 60 hours even if it is closer to the truth.

Comment: Upvote for you! Oh, wait...

Comment: Exactly. @Gmiby

Comment: Combine this answer with the answer by Hans Passant and the comment by Deduplicator and I think we probably have a pretty good picture of what happened.  It is interesting how peoples' behavior tends to change in a group vs. when they act alone...

Comment: Wow, with 18 votes, this answer must be true. Upvoted!

Answer (score 16):

The question has an unusual number of views, 801 when I first looked at it, you added another 113 :)  The vast majority of questions at SO peter out at ~25, give or take the popularity of the [tag].

It is still detectable how this happened, when you google the question for an exact phrase of the question title then you'll see hits at physics.stackexchange.com, serverfault.com, unix.stackexchange.com, stats.stackexchange.com and tex.stackexchange.com.

In other words, the question made it into the "Hot Network Questions" list, the one you see at the ==> right of this page.  Along with newsletter coverage and mention in aggregator sites like Reddit and HackerNews, this has a knack for ballooning the number of views on Q+A.  Heavy upvoting is a pretty inevitable result, especially for on trivial Q+A like this where just about anybody can tell that the posted answers are correct.

Exactly how the Q+A got this hotness factor is harder to guess.  It is done mechanically, it isn't a person that picks Q+A for inclusion in the list.  Voting velocity no doubt plays a role, again the triviality helps when everybody that initially looked at it know something about it and will vote.  And post the same answer.

It is a lottery, it just drew a lucky lot.

Comment: It seems to no longer exist. Some sort of cruel short-term win? Your number turned up but you tore up and set fire to the wrong "losing" ticket. Actually, it was only a small lottery prize, presumably. Wish I could see the reputation rolling off the asker and answerers :-)

Comment: It gathered enough delete votes just now, surely because of this meta question.  Five were needed to drive the stake, I seriously doubt it is going to be missed.  Well, other than by the FGITW posters.  Another lottery, hehe.

Comment: I didn't realise that could be done. I've got a list of popular crud. If I just post it on on meta, does that mean some of it may actually get deleted?

Comment: Personally I'd favor if SO users post their most-hated-question lists to meta.  I doubt it is going to be appreciated however, such lists tend to not hold up when scrutinized.  You can use a chat room to gather a posse.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll do a single exemplar and see how it progresses.

Comment: "harder to guess", gimme a break. Hotness formula is fairly straightforward. 1) 5 answers to that question in first half hour, score +5-6 (likely due to upvotes given to question by answerers) and voila, it hits the list. 2) Asker "reciprocally" upvotes every one of answers and hotness score increases to make it solid inhabitant of the list. 3) More upvotes from lemming visitors who [don't care about quality](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288471/839601) make it stick even more and gain even more senseless upvotes from hot list lemmings. It's not a rocket science, really

Answer (score 5):

There is also this phenomenon of "badge hunting" (amplified by the feature on the user page inciting people to hunt one badge after another), especially "Suffrage" and "Vox Populi", requiring that you vote dozens of times in a single day. You end up looking for 30 haystacks of upvotes to hide your 30 needles, without even reading what you vote for.