# Dupe-closing widely-viewed positively-received Qs with lots of up-votes towards rarely-viewed Qs?

Tags: discussion

There is a recent question I've favorited (starred) and been monitoring which has a lot of positive attention, views, and up-votes. The question has dozens of up-votes along with the answers, and there's a very interesting dynamic brewing there.

**Keeping the Community Engaged**

It is not a question I'm participating in directly. Feel free to check my recent activity if there's doubt. My vested interest here is only as a spectator and reader. It's rare to me in the areas I look at to see this much interest in something as opposed to an answer perfect for the FGITW who just fires one quickly and moves to the next question. To see a question with that much activity only tends to happen once every 10 pages worth of new questions in this area, while the majority of questions get a cynical, tired, and often routine response. These rare questions show me a community rising from the dead.

**Update with Example**

I got those looking around and trying to figure out which Q I'm talking about. So let me provide an example I'm comfortable to share of my own: [Can we implement a doubly-linked list using a single pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824969/can-we-implement-a-doubly-linked-list-using-a-single-pointer). This one got closed just when the activity was starting to skyrocket. Now since I participated in answering this one, I'm not coming at this from the angle of like, "Oh no, this question got shut down after I spent so much time on the answer!" (though in honesty, I do feel that a bit, but I didn't even have the best answer there and possibly even better ones could have come in). More disappointing was just having a C thread like that go away and then leaving us with either routine homework-style Qs or esoteric ones about APIs, microcontrollers, and OSes that often either get one answer or none.

**Definitely a Dupe But...**

Yet I was dismayed to find, days later, that someone discovered it to be a duplicate of a much older question, and now it has two close votes. I followed the redirection link and I must admit that this new question is, in fact, very much a duplicate of the old one. There is no dispute there.

The only subtle difference is that the old question is asking a slightly broader question (but slightly less general -- here "broad" as in requesting more details), so the answers there are "more complete" but "less specific". The bigger, more blatant difference is that the old question is old, obscure, and dusty, it only had 1 up-vote, and the answers aren't quite as varied and interesting (albeit almost all of them directly address the issue).

Now I don't want to link to this question here because my personal interest is to not see it closed. Let's just put this as a general question.

*What should we do in this case when a new question which has far more positive community interest, views, and activity, is a duplicate of an obscure, hardly-viewed question which didn't have anywhere near the momentum and interest and variety as the new one?*

**Momentum, Potential**

I almost want to suggest redirecting the old one to be a duplicate of the newer, superior, much more *mature* one (where *maturity* is defined by participation rather than age). I'm just sad to see this new question which has so much more energy going for it than the old being shut down because some obscure question which hardly anyone viewed existed long before. I'm all for site cleanliness but it's kind of sad when a Q&A which has so much momentum gets killed like this in favor of some dull relic of the past. With the higher traffic, momentum starts to become a factor in producing more interesting information (and carrying that potential). Momentum doesn't last, it's a fleeting quality (and more so with high traffic), and a question that is only periodically shut down could lose it forever.

I see site posterity and mitigating duplicates as a strong need on one hand, but also there's keeping the energy and positive activity and interest of the participants going on the other hand because of the potential that carries for *better answers than ever before*. Even from the pure site posterity angle, this somewhat redundant Q seems to be contributing vastly more useful information to the site than a very narrowly-applicable disposable question requesting to debug one's homework, relatively-speaking.

Comment: It looks like you are talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266487/multiple-aliases-for-a-namespace). If so, then what I'm seeing is a banal question with banal answers, not a question that "show[s] me a community rising from the dead".

Comment: @Louis Ah that's not the one -- though that one was really funny! I don't mind if that one is closed. I don't want to give too many hints, but it's a performance-related one.

Comment: Ok, then it's now closed. BTW: Which one *did* you mean? Also, I liked the "Student-Style Brace & Indent Guideline" ;-)

Comment: @Louis I also wiped it from my favs before asking since I imagined people would look for it with an effective SEDE query, e.g.

Comment: @Louis The case I'm talking about, if I can keep it rather vaguish (if people really must know I'll point it out) has a lot more than two answers (and far less routine than that one which ended up turning into a humorous vote on formatting style). I've been tempted to put a bounty on it recently to try to protect it.

Comment: If It's a Q & A "discussion" it sounds like it's off-topic.

Comment: @Ike The problem is that half the time when someone brings up a question like yours here, the issue is not so much with *what* principle should apply but with *how* to apply the principle. Without seeing the case itself, it is hard for us to know whether there is a problem with the *how* here.

Comment: @Paulie_D I must admit it's borderline discussion -- maybe even better suited for code review. :-(

Comment: @Louis I understand -- well, if it does get closed and it's not good enough to just speak about this generally, how about I link to it then and make a case to reopen? I imagined there were at least a number of examples that might fit that kind of case -- new question, very active, lots of answers going for it, being redirected to an obscure one. One thing I've always been wondering is, how might we then "transfer" the life of the original to the old one?

Comment: @Deduplicator Oh, here is one of my own that I'm comfortable sharing if people want an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824969/can-we-implement-a-doubly-linked-list-using-a-single-pointer. It got killed just when things were starting to get really interesting.

Comment: @Louis Lemme add this personal example to my question! It's already been closed so it's spilled milk. It does make my Q take on a slightly more selfish angle, but oh well -- it does seem better to talk about a concrete example.

Comment: @Ike The example helps. I see that the overwhelming majority of votes on that question were cast during the 1st day that question was on the site.  Is this par for the course nowadays for good C++ questions? (I'm not active there, so I don't know.) I see that the older question also got a spurt of votes on the first day. Could it be that the difference in raw numbers is due to changes in the quantity of people who get to look at a post as soon as it is posted rather than the inherent quality of the post?

Comment: By the way, the dupehammer was not used on that question. Take a look at the [tag info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/dupehammer/info) for "dupehammer". Either you need to edit your title to remove references to the hammer or your example does not quite fit.

Comment: @Louis The sadness of the C and C++ tags lately is that they've become flooded by VLQs or, Qs which are really difficult for anyone except a specialist to answer. But there is a lot of traffic there, but by far dominated by students with a, "I've been working on this all night, it's 2am, I have to turn this in 5 hours!" scenario. Coming from a professional background, I must admit it's very boring, and I talk to other people who frequent the tag and they seem to feel the same way. So I'm not sure if my description of the "community coming to life" is accurate or just a selfish kind...

Comment: @Louis ... continued from prev, I'm not sure if it's a selfish or accurate description, but it feels that way. Even putting aside my own concerns, just monitoring the nature of the voting there is dreary. [tag:c] is even worse lately.

Comment: @Louis Probably the ideal answer is for us to practice necromancy more -- but it doesn't seem to carry quite the same kind of momentum and energy to post answers to a really old and obscure question. The site seems to favor "newest" more than "active", and my worry is that when we have something which is definitely active and brimming with life, redirecting to an obscure duplicate can disengage the community, and also deprive the site of some potentially neat answers.

Comment: I get your frustration. I've mostly stopped going to [tag:selenium] due to the constant barrage of trivial, already answered, badly formulated questions. (I don't need to read yet another question whose answer is "tell Selenium to switch to the `iframe` that contains your element".) But I'm not convinced the solution entails switching around the duplicate-duplicated relationship in case similar to the one you brought up. Ideally, the answers on the duplicate question should be merged into the old one. This is not something I've worked on myself so I don't know how you go about getting it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wide views and lots of upvotes on the [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824969/can-we-implement-a-doubly-linked-list-using-a-single-pointer) are mostly because it hit the [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) list - which in turn happened because it quickly gained a lot of answers, as one can easily see at [the post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33824969/timeline)..

In cases like that, views and upvotes say nothing about question quality. Views and upvotes only reflect how many users have seen this question advertized on a [sidebar](/questions/tagged/sidebar).

---

To set the record straight for readers not familiar with Hot Network Questions purpose - it is established pretty firmly and it has nothing to do with content quality. The feature is there only to show network wide audience entertaining / interesting questions. If you're interested, refer MSE for more details on that: [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/165773)

Comment: Sounds like a good explanation of the number of votes and views. I tend to ignore the list so I did not think about it. Is there something in the timeline (or elsewhere) that indicates the question made it onto the the hot question list? Or are you inferring from the number of answers?

Comment: @Louis expand the "Nov 20 '15" entry in the timeline and you'll see that it has got 4 answers in less than an hour. Note by the way that I keep track of most SO questions that make it into hot list, so to me it was a matter of simple check whether it's in my list. On a side note, Hans Passant invented a [wonderful heuristics](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297669/839601) to detect whether question made it into HNQ, although I don't know how it will work for questions that has left the list

Comment: @Louis, gnat, from a purely selfish standpoint I tend to look at all the answers I've given (maybe people can understand my mindset a little better from my answers), and they're probably to questions which are a duplicate somewhere if we search hard enough. Yet I often spend over an hour providing these answers. Maybe I should spend an equal amount of time searching before I provide one, but honestly I'm just bored lately -- been taking part in SOCVR and I realize pretty much every question could be considered a duplicate of another except a troubleshoooting Q that is extremely...

Comment: @Louis, gnat ... specific to the author's needs, like those *"Please fix my code"* Qs -- except they're duplicating *issues* even if they aren't duplicating questions and answers. So I'm a very late joiner to SO, only recently started participating a lot, but already I'm so terribly bored by the lack of activity, lack of interesting things to read that teach me a lot, lack of interesting things to answer that seem worth investing my time. It might be a symptom very specific to C and C++ tags -- but I'm so bored that I'm starting to do stuff like this...

Comment: @Louis gnat -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829566/for-loop-with-pointer-in-c/33829743?noredirect=1#comment56315739_33829743. I've been tempted to just bounty off all my rep and just try to force people to get interested -- I want to find more of those Mysticial-quality answers again... or even just someone who invests a lot of effort into a basic question -- mostly I see a community as bored as I am, with a lot of enthusiasm going into moderation rather than sharing expertise.

Comment: @Louis gnat -- this might be very much a symptom of  C and C++. C++ tends to be flooded by slightly less VLQs since the language is much more complex -- questions about metaprogramming and SFINAE, for example, are far from exhausted. C, on the other hand, is a very basic language, with a standard library far simpler than, say, Python. So it's bound to spawn duplicates repeatedly outside of any API-specific territory, unless it's a homework question or a performance one that rewards understanding computer architecture more than the avg. C programmer.

Comment: @Louis gnat, I also never look at that "hot" questions list, but can't speak for all users. As a C/C++ watcher above all else, I tend to look at "newest' questions -- looking for something that won't get a routine answer, a lot of down-votes, or is very API-specific (ex: a question about an API or embedded hardware that's very esoteric that probably no one will answer). It's rare to find anything that generates lots of activity -- I tend to judge only the amount of activity and the quality of the answers... the question could be extremely terse, lacking detail.